# Using feign client for interal and external service communication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service-discovery, feign

We have multiple services for which we use feign client for communication (All of the being spring boot applications). However, I have scenario where we have to communicate with external service. It works if I pass `url` but I want to know if this is the right thing to do.

```
 @FeignClient(
    name = "foo",
    url = "${some.url.from.env}",
    configuration = FeignConfiguration.class) 

public interface FooClient {
  @PostMapping("search/{searchQuery}")
  ResponseEntity<JsonNode> getData(
      @RequestBody POJO someObject);
```

Any advice is appreciated.

PS: sorry if I did not follow the stackoverflow rules (My first post).

Answer (score 0):

It's completely ok. The main idea of this library (https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) is to help you with writing any HTTP clients easier, in a more declarative way.

Later, it was integrated with Spring Cloud by https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign, and one of the ideas of that "wrapper" was to manage requests between microservices built with Spring Cloud. But it's not the one and only use of it.